# Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F9 doesn't always recalculate

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using Excel 365 and I have `Calculation Options` set to `Manual`. As far as I know the `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F9` shortcut is supposed to recalculate all cells in the entire workbook, even if some of them don't need to be recalculated (or something like that). Most of the time it works fine but recently I found one spreadsheet where this shortcut will not always recalculate cells: it will freeze the computer for a few secs meaning it is performing **some** work but when it finishes most (or all?) cells seem to be untouched. I don't know whether it doesn't recalculate any of them or just some of them. It also seems to be random when this shortcut does and does not seem to work (sometimes it works just fine).

Generally, are there any exceptions or situations where `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F9` might not work (or stop working e.g. upon an error)? I couldn't find anything on google.

Comment: Excel 365 Recalculate All is Ctrl-Alt-F9   Have you tried that?  Is your F9 key dual purpose so that F9 is something else?

Comment: Yes, same result. (I've also just updated my question to specify Excel version.)

Comment: Maybe try an Office Full Repair to see if that helps. Otherwise I am not certain.

Comment: Do you have **Fn** keyboard?

Comment: If you mean that instead of `F9` the keyboard is sending another signal then that's not it. There's a chance it's something specific to my sheet and functions/stuff it uses but unfortunately I cannot post it here for you to check.